# Profilegrid login/reset pasword anr errors

Tags: php, wordpress

We're having trouble with the profilegrid wordpress plugin.

For the login page:

When the password is incorrect it displays: You entered incorrect password. Please try again or click on “Forgot Password” which is correct behaviour. 
But when the correct password is filled in you are redirected to the /wp-login.php page I'm assuming because of an error.

For the lost password page:

When any username is filled in (doesn't need to exist) there comes a message:

> An unknown error occurred. Please try again later.

and the url changes to `.../forgot-password/?**errors=anr_error**`.

We don't know what causes this, does anyone know how to fix this?

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Apparently the current users have been imported using a .csv file from previous website. With this file there were no passwords included, so all the users now don't have a password.

Can this cause internal errors for the plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there's a conflict between google recaptcha plugins and the profilegrid reset password and login pages.

We disabled the google recaptcha for the login and lost password pages and now it works again.